# Column Value Conversion

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I Have a table called Data and it has a column called Key which is of type varbinary.

The sample Values of that column are:

```
Key:

0x7F16D4BFA88C67E4F786DBC193C833DA
0x92CECEF9F5D6368CE4F2B0594B766775
```

Now i want to assign this value to a column called `S_Key` in another table `Final_Data` But the problem is `S_Key` is of `Datatype Varchar`.I tried convert and Cast but none of them seems to be working can anyone help me on this?

I did try this:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),0x3224CB7E4CEF0D2F6108ADFEA39BD233)
```

but it is giving me value like this:

```
2$Ë~Lï /a­þ£›Ò3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using the built-in `sys.fn_sqlvarbasetostr` function to convert it to a hex-encoded string.

Comment: It still gives me output as 0x25bdaf0948a57b502c968bf83d90af97

Comment: @Sam - thats because it's showing you the hex string representation of the binary data.  I believe that is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
select master.dbo.fn_varbintohexstr([key]) 
    from Data
```